# C# Give Permissions to Everyone in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

We want to give permissions (in .Net Application) to everyone in AD but could not find the group that contains everyone.  Tried with “NT Authority\Authenticated Users” but getting "user not found". Please provide any pointers to achieve this functionality.Below is sample code snippet.

```
DirectorySearcher user = new DirectorySearcher(connString);
user.Filter = String.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", alias);
var result = user.FindOne();
```

Note:  we can give permissions to all the users in SharePoint using  “All Authenticated Users” but the same option is not working in .Net Application.

Regards,
Parveen

Answer (score 1):

In a domain, everyone means all the Domain users, so in order to give permission to all domain users you need to use this: DOMAIN\Domain Users